# calling a function from within a different project in C++ ( in Linux )

Tags: c++, linux, methods, callback

**Problem:** I have two projects in C++:

1. Project 01
2. Project 02

In Project 01 we have, P01Raja.cpp with `method1(argc, argv)`.
In project 02, We have P02Rani.cpp with `method2()`.

Now, I want to call my method1 (from P01Raja.cpp) in method2 (from P01Rani.cpp).

P01Raja.cpp is located at /home/krishna/Project 01/src/P01Raja.cpp
P02Rani.cpp is located at /usr/local/project 02/P02Rani.cpp

I'm working in GNU Linux but not in a Windows environment.

Note: I'm a Java expert and know C++ basics.

Comment: Same as always. Include the header and link against the object code.

Comment: Thanks a lot ignacio vazquez abramas. Pls provide the Code snippet for linking aganist object code. {i don't know this silly one even :=) }

Comment: Provide all .o files to link against on the `gcc`/`g++` command line.

Comment: Do you know how to make a `make` file?

Answer (score 0):

`#include "/home/krishna/Project 01/src/P01Raja.cpp"`

Comment: Hi Redmastif, i did #include /home/krishna/Project 01/src/P01Raja.cpp to get the method1. But still GCC asking me for dependency in P01Raja.cpp. :=)

Comment: Hi Redmastif,  I'm getting below error - " error: property was not declared in this scope "